# Converting html returned from ajax request into an object causes weird complications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am calling an Ajax request with jQuery:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $(data).find('ul');
});
```

And here is a problem - it does not find any ul.

Returned HTML code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Mobilna wersja serwisu GoldenLine." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="praca, networking, forum, blog, bran?a" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://css.goldenline.pl/mobile.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://x/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a id="h" href="http://x/"><img src="http://x/img/mobile.gif" alt="GoldenLine" /></a></h1>
    <h2>Moje grupy</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/estimating-software">estimating software</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/google-hacking">Google hacking</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/google-plus">Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/praca-dla-informatykow">IT – Praca dla osób z...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/jezyki-skryptowe">Języki Skryptowe</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://x/img/ico-post.png" alt="" />
            <a href="http://x/forum/netcamp">Netcamp</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="setAsRead"><a href="http://x/fora/ozn">Ozn</a></p>
    <form method="get" action="http://x/szukaj">
        <input type="text" name="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Szukaj" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li>1. <img src="http://x/img/msg_box_ico.gif" alt="" /> <a href="http://x/skrzynka" accesskey="1">Skrzynka [0]</a></li>
        <li>2. <a href="http://x/kontakty" accesskey="2">Kontakty</a></li>
        <li>3. <a href="http://x/forum" accesskey="3">Moje grupy</a></li>
        <li>4. <a href="http://x/wylogowanie" accesskey="4">Wyloguj</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>2010 &copy; Goldenline.pl | <a href="http://x/www">przejdź do normalnej wersji serwisu</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I convert it into an object

```
$(data)
```

I got something like this:

```
[
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->, 
Text, 
<title>?GoldenLine.pl?</title>?, 
Text, 
<meta http-equiv=?"content-type" content=?"application/?xhtml+xml;? charset=utf-8">?, 
Text, 
<meta name=?"description" content=?"Mobilna wersja serwisu GoldenLine.">?, 
Text, 
<meta name=?"keywords" content=?"praca, networking, forum, blog, bran?a">?, 
Text, 
<link rel=?"stylesheet" type=?"text/?css" href=?"http:?/?/?css.goldenline.pl/?mobile.css">?, 
Text, 
<link rel=?"shortcut icon" href=?"http:?/?/?m.goldenline.pl/?favicon.ico">?, 
Text, 
<h1>?…?</h1>?, 
Text, 
<h2>?Moje grupy?</h2>?, 
Text, 
<ul>?…?</ul>?, 
Text, 
<p class=?"setAsRead">?…?</p>?, 
Text, 
<form method=?"get" action=?"http:?/?/?m.goldenline.pl/?szukaj">?…?</form>?, 
Text, 
<ul>?…?</ul>?, 
Text, 
<div class=?"footer">?…?</div>?, 
Text, 
<script type=?"text/?javascript">?…?</script>?, 
Text
]
```

What should I do to match `<ul>` elements in this piece of code returned from Ajax request ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think you should first insert returned html data in one html element.

```
var mytag=$('<div></div>').html(data);
```

now using jQuery you can extract all ul nodes.

```
$('ul',mytag);
```

it will return array of all ul tags.

Comment: Sure - it works in this case, but if I convert any other webpage's html code into an object, it works fine - but not with this case. Packing whole html into div is a bit rude way.

Comment: dear hsz... your approach for finding 'ul' tag was perfect. but as you told it was working in one case and not in other case. let me clear the reason. the reason was- when you make object using jQuery(data) then it make an hierarchy of nodes, and when you find some node like 'ul', it searches in whole hierachy except root elements, and our 'ul' tags were root elements. if you search the child elements, results will be positive. so the solution in your manner can be - jQuery('<div></div>').append(jQuery(data)).find('ul') and it will give you again perfect result.

Answer (score 1):

Your return format is not `html`, looks rather like JSON to me. Try to enforce HTML by

```
$.get(url, function(data){
    $(data).find('ul');
}, "html");
```

Next thing I'd do is to see what the Content-Type of the server response is (using FireBug or something similar). It should say `text/html` there. If not, then the problem is probably on your back end, need to ensure that it sets the Content-Type correctly.

Tried it on my machine, if the Content-Type is OK, then it works like a charm, also without enforcing `html` in the `jQuery.get`.

Comment: I've tried to set content-type during request but it didn't help - it works the same way as before. `user907376` solution works but it is very rude way to go.

Comment: And the response Content-Type showed to be 'text/html' in Firebug? This would be really weird. But at least you got a working solution now. But something must still be wrong, because this should work without the "wrapper solution" imo...